# GRUB build fails to compile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, grub2

I cloned grub from Github https://github.com/coreos/grub, however it fails to compile and gives error. The error seems obvious but the point is how the upstream code is not compiling. Am I doing anything wrong?

I did below things to compile :

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=efi
make
```

I get this error :

```
grub_script.yy.c: In function ‘yy_fatal_error’:
grub_script.yy.c:19:22: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
 #define fprintf(...) 0
                      ^
grub_script.yy.c:2367:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘fprintf’
  fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", msg );
  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:35746: recipe for target 'normal_module-grub_script.yy.o' failed
make[3]: *** [normal_module-grub_script.yy.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/grub-2.02/grub-core'
Makefile:23531: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/grub-2.02/grub-core'
Makefile:10904: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/grub-2.02'
Makefile:3130: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried with gcc 4.8,5 as well as 7, but the same error. My host machine is Ubuntu-18 64-bit.

Comment: Did you already ask upstream about this issue?

Comment: @Jens : Yes, before raising this question, I also reported this on the mail thread for GRUB. No response received so far.

Comment: That looks like a pretty ancient fork of grub. Is the problem also existent in actual upstream: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/grub.git? I'm not seeing any reports obviously about this topic on either https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-grub or https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/grub-devel - where did you sent the reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jens comments, the upstream maintainers should fix this build break. On the
face of it the fix seems simple. Meantime a workaround is simple too, and almost certainly safe.

As you see from the failing build log, you get this compilation error only
because the `-Werror` flag is in effect, to promote all warnings to errors.

The promoted warning that is breaking your build occurs in file `grub_script.yy.c` at line 2367.
It is in fact innocuous warning. You can cause it *not* to be promoted in either of two ways:-

The `./configure` script has an option `--disable-werror`, which removes the `-Werror`
flag from all compilations. So you can run:

```
$ ./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=efi --disable-werror
$ make
```

This solution will cause *no* compilation warnings to be promoted to errors, and
is likely what you are "supposed" to be content with. You might prefer a somewhat more focussed workaround that disables
error-promotion *only* for the type of warning that actually broke your build:

```
statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
```

You can accomplish that with:

```
$ ./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=efi CPPFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-value
$ make
```